# Android - SQLite Database retrieving of values then output as looped Checkboxes based on the amount of IDs in Database

Tags: android, arrays, json, checkbox, android-edittext

[Mock Up of the App I'm trying to make.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjg3Z.png)

SELECTION:

New to Android but I'm trying to retrieve the values from my SQLite [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjg3Z.png) and make a continuous loop of checkboxes based on the amount of IDs stored. The checkboxes will just output the subject name. If possible it should output subject name and units. Can you help me?

```js
     //get all subjects
    public List < Subject > getAllSubjects() {

      List < Subject > subjectList = new ArrayList < Subject > ();
      //select all query
      String selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SUBJECTS;
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      //loop through all rows and add it to list
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
          Subject subject = new Subject();
          subject.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
          subject.setSubName(cursor.getString(1));
          subject.setUnits(cursor.getString(2));
          //ADD CONTACT TO LIST
          subjectList.add(subject);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      return subjectList;
    }
```

Need a syntax or code example on how I can retrieve the subjectList values into MainActivity and output them as looped Checkboxes and/or ListViews.

Comment: @jankigadhiya sorry about that, just added my code now.

Comment: Please be clear about your question.. i cannot understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @jankigadhiya I'm trying to make an app that will store 2 EditText into one Array. I then implement a button which opens a dialog box, and in the dialog box is a checkbox listview of the array values entered. I can select the values and submit, then all the selected values in the checkbox will be shown in another screen. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: **2 EditText into one Array**, Then there will always be only two values in your listview.. If i haven't got it wrong..!!

Comment: Is it possible to somehow add the 2 EditText together then store them as a array value and retrieve them as one checkbox? Could you show me an example?

Comment: EditText1 is having value "xyz", EditText2 is having value "abc". How you want to store them ?? Array will only contain two items always i.e. {"xyz","abc"}. You will display them on list and get the selected items.. Right??

Comment: Yup, exactly like that. If you want an easier explanation: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YCZS3.png this is what I'm trying to make. I'm currently on Add College Class Subject and Selection of those entered values. Left to right, top to bottom.

Comment: In this image you are having more then two data in your listview with check boxes.. where will be they coming from. If you have only two edittexts.

Comment: From Add College Class Subject, they don't necessarily have to be 2 data, as long as they give a single String value of the Class Subject and Units. In my code I just combined the 2 EditText into 1 String, I just want to display that string in an array checkbox. And when multiple checkboxes are selected it will be saved. 

PS: Please disregard the total units in the profile page and teachers list. I just want to show all the subjects they are teaching, and their individual corresponding units that have been entered in the EditText on Add College Class Subject.

Comment: Why you are saving that to File?? use database instead.. it will be more helpful in your case.

Comment: I just store it to internal, external, and shared preferences because of my requirement. I'd love to use a database, but I have no idea how to and how to save my EditTexts or Checkboxes there. We also have to implement JSON for the teacher's list and profile page, but my teacher barely taught anything and he's on leave at the moment, so I don't know how to do that either. But you're really right on the database thing, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: You do not have to store EditText in Data base.. Just get the value of that and store. I will try to help you for that thing.

Comment: Oh, okay. Please do! My teacher lets us use XAMPP, but I can't remember how to use it. So all in all, I just need to learn how to input text to EditText to store the values in the database, then retrieve the values for the checkboxes and save again for the output in JSON list.

Comment: see my answer..!! i hope it will help..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First refer this link : [Learn SQLITE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm).

With the help of above tutorial Create two tables named **Subjects** & **Teachers**, The structure of tables will be like this:

Subject : ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREAMENT, NAME text, UNITS text.

Teachers : ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREAMENT, NAME text, Subjects text.

**For add class Subject**.

There will be two edittexts 1st will have Sub name and second will have number of Units. Take that two values in separate string on button click and store the in **Subjects** table. Now your subject table will contain a record like:

```
Id         Name       Units
1        Subject-1      4
```

Like this go on entering Subjects.

**For add teachers and assignments**

You will be having one edittext in which name of the teacher will be entered. One selection button, On the click of that button You can show the list of subject from our **Subjects Table**.

on click of `Ok` in dialog you can get selected subjects.

**Submit** button click, Save the teachers data in table **Teachers**.Store only id's of subject comma separated. After that refer a particular by its id only.

Now the teachers table will be having data like :

```
Id         Name       Subjects
1         daniel         1,2
```

**For the list of Teachers**

Show the list from our Teachers table.

> EDIT 2: **For Setting the list to listView**

Refer this link : [How to set list in ListView+CheckBoxes](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

I am summarizing the concept here:

**Step : 1**

You need to create a `list_item.xml` layout which will contain a TextView And a Check box only Horizontally placed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step : 2**

You need to create an adapter which will be taking care of your list which will be set to the listView.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Subject> {

private ArrayList<Subject> subList;

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                       ArrayList<Subject> subList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, subList);
    this.subList = new ArrayList<Subject>();
    this.subList.addAll(subList);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    CheckBox chk_box;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.chk_box = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Subject subject = subList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(subject.getSubName() + " - " + subject.getUnits());


    return convertView;

}

}
```

**Step - 3**

Set this adapter to you ListView in MainActivty:

**Create another `xml` activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivty.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView mylist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    mylist.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(MainActivty.this,subjectList,R.layout.list_item));
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has clarified a lot of my questions. Currently working on my code, hopefully it'll workout the way I hope it should.

Comment: My pleasure it helped.. Happy coding :)

Comment: So far so good, would it be possible if you give me or link me a sample code on how I can retrieve the SQLite Database Table Subjects - Name and/or Units to output the value on Checkboxes so the user can see what he/she is selecting? Thanks! I'm currently working on the selection button. http://imgur.com/CDsvR9a

Comment: You have changed the question..!!

Comment: @jankigdhiy users unfortunately marked it as too broad, so I had to make sure to specify what I really need. At the moment I need the syntax or code example on how I can retrieve values from my SQLite Database and put it in my MainActivity so I can ListView it. :\

Comment: Thnx for accepting the answer by Refer this link to set your list with check boxes. : http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: Thank you! Is there a specific syntax in which I could retrieve my Subject table from my DatabaseHandler and output it? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: You are retrieving the data perfectly. as you provided the code in your question you just need to set your `subjectList` in a ListView. Follow my link step by step you will definitely get what you want..!!

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm just wondering what would be the java code to retrieve from my DatabaseHandler and put it on the XML? Do I just create a ListView and add subjectList as it's ID? Or is there a java code where I retrieve from the DatabaseHandler and add to my Selection.java and loop it so it will show multiple LIstViews with checkboxes that can be stored in another DatabaseHandler?

Comment: No need to store them just follow the steps i have described  in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Currently implementing Step 3 , haven't made a ListView java code in MainActivity but currently searching.

Comment: just wondering, is that supposed to be textview or listview on the XML you've added?